# Delete child one deeper in firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

[image: How do I delete this child circled in the red below if I do not know the child after following]

I want to delete the child node that is circled above. Anyone know how can I do that if the child before is unknown?

Comment: This is possible you can query one level below an autoID or an id that is unknown. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44689303/firebase-retrieve-data-below-auto-id-in-swift

Comment: Awesome, thanks @DoesData