# How can I get some arrays from Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a beginner of Swift and Firebase. I want to get some String arrays as array values. This is my json tree in database.

[image: my tree]

And I tried to get them using Class(named UserInfoClass) which has a snapshot as an argument and retrieve their value as [String]. But I ran with this following codes, optional nil error came out.

```
func retriveData(){

    refUserInfo = Database.database().reference().child("users")
    refUserInfo.observe(.value) { (snapshot)  in
        let info = UserInfoClass.init(snapshot: snapshot)
        //userInfo is [UserInfoClass]
        self.userInfo.append(info!)
        self.InfoTableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

This is 'UserInfoClass'.

```
 init? (snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        guard let applyDict = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "ApplyInfo").value as? [String: Any] else {return nil }
        guard let peopleNum = applyDict["peopleNum"] as? Int else { return nil }
        print("peopleNum: \(peopleNum)\n")

        guard let payType = applyDict["payType"] as? [String] else { return nil }
        print("payType:\(payType)\n")
        guard let receiveType = applyDict["receiveType"] as? [String] else { return nil }
        print("receiveType: \(receiveType)\n")
        guard let furigana2 = applyDict["furigana2"] as? [String] else { return nil }
        print("furigana2: \(furigana2)")
        guard let prayman2 = applyDict["prayman2"] as? [String] else { return nil }
        print("prayman2: \(prayman2)\n")
        guard let furigana1 = applyDict["furigana1"] as? [String] else { return nil }
        print("furigana1:\(furigana1)\n")
        guard let prayman1 = applyDict["prayman1"] as? [String] else { return nil }
        print("prayman1:\(prayman1)\n")
        guard let prayType2 = applyDict["prayType2"] as? [String] else { return nil }
        print("prayType2:\(prayType2)\n")
        guard let prayType1 = applyDict["prayType1"] as? [String] else { return nil }
        print("prayType1:\(prayType1)")
        guard let moneySum = applyDict["moneySum"] as? [Int] else { return nil }
        print("moneySum:\(moneySum)\n")

        guard let fuda1Small = applyDict["fuda1S"] as? [String] else {return nil}
        guard let fuda1Mid = applyDict["fuda1M"] as? [String] else {return nil}
        guard let fuda1Large = applyDict["fuda1L"] as? [String] else {return nil}
        guard let fuda3Small = applyDict["fuda3S"] as? [String] else {return nil}
        guard let fuda3Mid = applyDict["fuda3M"] as? [String] else {return nil}
        guard let fuda3Large = applyDict["fuda3L"] as? [String] else {return nil}
        guard let fuda5Small = applyDict["fuda5S"] as? [String] else {return nil}
        guard let fuda5Mid = applyDict["fuda5M"] as? [String] else {return nil}
        guard let fuda5Large = applyDict["fuda5L"] as? [String] else {return nil}
```

How can I do that?
Thank you.

Comment: You should generally avoid using arrays when possible. See [Arrays are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html). If you can clarify what your trying to do we may be able to help. Are you trying to get the two values within each node? (fuda1L, fuda1M) etc? Or something else?

Comment: I understood that using array is not appropriate when there are some users who can change datas at time, thank you. Yes, I tried to get two values in each node. This was because that I wanted to save multiple user's datas(like fuda1L[0] is personA, fuda1L[1] is personB.) corresponding to the date of saving them. So, not using the array, I am going to use childByAutoId with the saved date and with each person of the date node.  How could I get value all person data with making distinction of saved date?

Comment: Number of person is mutable.

Comment: I'll try like this. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44689303/firebase-retrieve-data-below-auto-id-in-swift)

Comment: Take a look at the link I provided... *some users who can change datas at time* is not the reason to not use arrays in NoSQL databases. Using childByAutoId is the way to go for sure, however *How could I get value all person data with making distinction of saved date?* I don't understand that question - are you asking how to query for a specific person by date? That may be unrelated to this question so it would probably be better to ask a different question with you new code and structure.